# RSS with SAX parser

Tags: android, rss

I want to put AsyncTask instead thread in this simple code of SAX RSS parser 
in ListFragment , and what is better Asynctask or multi thread.

this is my code

public class ListItem extends ListFragment  {

```
public  ArrayList<NewsItem> getValues() {
        return values;
}

public void setValues(ArrayList<NewsItem> values) {
        this.values = values;
}

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        handler = new Handler();
}

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_news_layout, container, false);
        return view;
}
enter code here
public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
}

public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        refresh();
        listAdapter = new ListAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.listitem,
                        getValues());
        setListAdapter(listAdapter);

}
enter code here
public void refresh() {
        Thread th = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                        ListHandler listHandler = new ListHandler();
                        try {
                                listHandler.processFeed();
                                setValues(listHandler.getNewsItemList());
                                listAdapter.setNewsItemList(getValues());
                                listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                }
        });
        th.start();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually Asynctask is also using thread but it is better for onpostexecute and onprexecute()
method callback if you use thread you dont get this by default .

Like this

```html
private class HttpAsyncDealsTask extends
   AsyncTask<String, Void, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>> {

  protected ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> doInBackground(
    String... dealslist) {

   ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> chekinRsp = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
   // get user data from session
   HashMap<String, String> user = session.getUserDetails();
   // mem_id
   String mem_id = user.get(SessionManager.KEY_ID);
   String rest_id = getArguments().getString("getid");
   try {

    List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(
      2);

    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("rest_id", rest_id));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("mem_id", mem_id));
    // Creating service handler class instance
    ServiceHandler sh = new ServiceHandler();

    // Making a request to url and getting response
    String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(URL, ServiceHandler.POST,
      nameValuePairs);

    Log.d("Response: ", "> " + jsonStr);
    if (jsonStr != null) {
     try {
      // creating new HashMap
      HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
      JSONObject jresponse = new JSONObject(jsonStr);
      JSONObject msg = jresponse.getJSONObject(KEY_MSG);
      //String error = jresponse.getString(KEY_ERROR);
      String msgss = msg.getString(KEY_MSGSS);
      String error = msg.getString(KEY_ERROR);
      
      if(error.equalsIgnoreCase("0"))
      {
       String getid = getArguments().getString("getid");
       String getname = getArguments().getString("getname");
       String getpoints = getArguments().getString("getpoints");
       String getcomp = getArguments().getString("getcomp");
       String getmemberpoint = getArguments().getString("getmemberpoint");
       
       System.out.println(getid + getname + getpoints + getcomp + getmemberpoint);
       
       CheckinPref checkin = new CheckinPref(getActivity());
          checkin.Prefernce_save(getid
            ,getname, getpoints
            ,getcomp, getmemberpoint);
       
      }
      
      map.put(KEY_MSGSS, msgss);
      chekinRsp.add(map);
      // Log.d("OUT", msg);
     } catch (JSONException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
     }

    }

   } catch (Exception e) {
    Log.d("Response", e.getLocalizedMessage());
   }

   return chekinRsp; // return result
  }

  @Override
  protected void onPostExecute(
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> chekinRsp) {
   System.out.println(chekinRsp.get(0).get(KEY_MSGSS));

   TextView chekinResp = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(
     R.id.chekinResp);
   chekinResp.setText(chekinRsp.get(0).get(KEY_MSGSS));

   Button backButton = (Button) getActivity().findViewById(
     R.id.btn_restback);
   backButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {

     FragmentManager fm = getActivity().getFragmentManager();
     fm.popBackStack();
    }
   });

  }

 }
```

and start this using
new HttpAsyncDealsTask().execute();